# How to add part to regex replace?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to automatically detect links in content and create hyperlinks.

I support `http`, `https` and `www`.

The problem is, that when my regex find the `www` link, it should prepend `http://` to the result.

I know I could use a `str_replace()` or `strpos()` etc. but can this be done using the `preg_replace()`?

### PHP

```
$input = '<p>Hello, visit http://stackoverflow.com or www.stackoverflow.com</p>';
$regex_url = '~(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(?:www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i';
echo preg_replace( $regex_url, '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $input );
```

### Result

```
<p>Hello, visit <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">http://stackoverflow.com</a> or <a href="www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">www.stackoverflow.com</a></p>
```

Comment: Excuse me, is the **Result** an expected  result?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, it is my current result, the result of the code above.

Comment: This sounds like a 2 steps work...

Comment: But how do you know if `http` or `https` should be added?

Comment: I don't, but since the link is provided as `www.stackoverflow.com` and I cannot be sure if it supports `https` I guess it is safest to use `http`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea how you want to deduce if `http://` or `https://` are required in each concrete case, but it is easy to achieve with a replace callback:

```
$input = '<p>Hello, visit http://stackoverflow.com or www.stackoverflow.com</p>';
$regex_url = '~(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(?:www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i';
echo preg_replace_callback( $regex_url, function($m) {
    return substr($m[0], 0, 4) == "http" ?
        '<a href="' . $m[0] . '" target="_blank">' . $m[0] . '</a>':
        '<a href="http://' . $m[0] . '" target="_blank">http://' . $m[0] . '</a>';
}, $input);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/dNUDRC)

Inside the callback, I check the match value with `substr($m[0], 0, 4) == "http"`. If it starts with `http`, I just use the match value. If not, I add it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
<?php
$input = '<p>Hello, visit https://stackoverflow.com or http://stackoverflow.com or www.stackoverflow.com</p>';
$regex_url = '~(?:http(s?)://|(www\.))([^\s<]+)(?<![\.,:])~i';
echo preg_replace( $regex_url, '<a href="http$1://$2$3" target="_blank">$0</a>', $input );
?>
```

It's a bit ugly since it relies on capturing either `s?` or `www...`